# std::string append too slow?

Tags: c++

I have a situation where I read data from a struct and keep appending it to a string so that it can be sent over a socket. When the data is fairly large, this operation is taking a lot of time. Can someone suggest any alternatives?

I have a structure

> struct fileInfo
>    {
>       int file_id;
>       char filename[16];
>       double tag;
>     }

I do a std::stringstream >>file_id and stringstream.str()
this is repeated for each value, appended to a string and sent

Comment: What you have posted is reading from a `stringstream`, not writing. There is no appending happening there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::ostringstream` from `<sstream>` is designed for exactly that mode of operation.

```
ostringstream my_text;
my_text << "hello " << 2 << foo << endl; // efficiently catenate

socket.send( my_text.str() ); // get a std::string to handle data
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should send the strings individually. If you have a streaming socket, this should make no difference to the way the data is received at the other end.

Comment: you mean, instead of appending, just do a send?

Comment: @Rajesh: He's saying, if the I/O is locally buffered, then don't worry about buffering it yourself. I'm guessing that the socket isn't buffered since most aren't.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an [std::stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/). More specific help can only be provided if you provide more specific information. What kind of data are you streaming? How large are the chunks of data?

Comment: Thats what I use. I read the struct value into a stringstream and then do a .str() to get the string. Can I directly send a stringstream?

Comment: @Rajesh: You said you use a `string`, not a `stringstream`. They have different runtime characteristics for appending, so it's a rather important difference. What makes you say the `stringstream` is slow? What does the profiler point at specifically?

Comment: I do use a string...i append the stringstream.str to a string and then send

Answer (score 0):

If you can have a rough estimate about how large the string will end up, you could use std::string::reserve() first to avoid superfluous reallocations later.